# How to show a process in android

Tags: android

My problem is that, i have a function sync() in my class MyDB which extends SQLiteDatabase
on a click of a button, i call this function 
as

```
    db.open();
    db.sync();
    db.close();
```

its working fine, but it takes some time and while that time the activity stucks.
I need to show a working process on a dialogue instead of this stucking. I need not to show the 'progress' of this syncing, I am concerned only that when activity stucks, there must be a process in the form of rotating circle or something like that. How can i do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Best method to do it..  is to use an inner class that extends Asyntask.. and then override onpreexecute(), onpostexecute() and doinbackground() methods, and do what you want

Answer (score 1):

i think you can use this code:

```
private ProgressDialog dialog;
dialog = new ProgressDialog(this.activity);
```

and:

```
this.dialog.setMessage("Please Wait");
this.dialog.show();
```

Comment: hmmm.. yeah.. but cant i have a rotating circle, or something which is moving !

Comment: did you check that it has n't got rotating circle?i've used it and it has one ;)

Comment: Hey..  thnx.. it has a rotating circle..   Thanx a lot...  :-)

Comment: your wellcome but i don't know why i got -1 on my answer? anyway good luck

Comment: Hey...  its  not working with this function..  i used it like this:

Comment: dialog.setMessage("Syncing...");
   dialog.show();
   db.open();
   db.sync();
   db.close();
                        dialog.dismiss();